# Android - How to do a bi directional binding with com.android.databinding:dataBinder?

Tags: android, data-binding, bidirectional

How to do a bi directional binding (from UI to data and from data to UI) using the new dataBinder plugin ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have this yet, maybe after v1. Not sure what your use case is but we already create fields for each View with an id so when you need the data, you can get it using that view.

e.g. if you have `<EditText android:id="@+id/mytext"/>`

Generated binding class will have `public final EditText mytext;`.

Comment: In rc1, you can have event handlers for any event in the view. For example, 'android:onTextChanged="@{myObj.textChanged}"'. I know it isn't two-way data binding, but it does make life a little easier.

Comment: Two-way data binding has become available in the meantime for various components. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/111/data-binding-library/6634/built-in-two-way-data-binding#t=201704111334151449175 for details

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="bind" type="com.example.app.MainActivity.Bind"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onTextChanged="@{bind.textChanged}"
            android:text="@{bind.text}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and activity code (using retrolambda):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Bind bind = new Bind();

    public class Bind {
        public ObservableField<String> text = new ObservableField<>();

        public TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged textChanged = (s, start, before, count) -> {
            System.out.println("New value: " + s);
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setBind(bind);
    }
}
```